# Prove convergence of improper integral of hard to factor denominator

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am trying to determine whether $$ \int_{-3}^{2} \frac{xdx}{x^3+2x+2}\,.$$ converges or diverges

Usually, for improper integrals where there is a vertical asymptote, I try to split the integral up around the asymptote, but I can't really do that here cause I cannot factor it. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: This integral does not converge on the given interval

Comment: How would I actually go about proving that? I thought the same thing when I looked at the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The denominator is positive at $0$ and negative at $-1,$ hence must be $0$ somewhere in between.

Comment: Yeah I realized that when I saw the graph. Should I just approximate the asymptote and do comparison tests on the approximate sub-intervals?